# Playwright 'Re-use state' & 'Re-use Authentication' with Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, testing, automation, playwright

I'm trying to make sure that in each test that runs, I don't have to log in to the platform I'm testing. To achieve this, I'm implementing 'Re-use state' & 'Re-use Authentication'. However, Firebase uses indexedDB instead of Cookies or SessionStorage. StorageState does not persist the indexedDB here. Maybe you know a solution for this?

global-setup.ts:

```
import { Browser, chromium, expect, Page } from "@playwright/test";

async function globalSetup(){
  const browser = await chromium.launch({headless: false});
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page: Page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto("<'url'>")
  await page.getByLabel('Email').fill('<'email'>');
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('<'password'>');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
  await expect (page.getByRole('link', { name: 'logo' })).toBeVisible({ timeout: 30000 });

  //save state
  await page.context().storageState({ path: "./LoginAuth.json" });

  await browser.close();
}

export default globalSetup;
```

usefull links:

https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#reuse-authentication-in-playwright-test
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11164

Answer (score 3):

it's possible to also store the indexedDB in the storageState, and then restore it later, tho you have to jump through some hoops to do it.

What I did was store the indexedDB in my localStorage, so that when you save the storageState, you have all it's contents. It works by saving the database name as the key, and the stringified JSON of the database's storage objects as values, so each entry in the localStorage is a database. I'm using the basic authentication in playwright's [authentication documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#basic-shared-account-in-all-tests), so in the setup file use the following code:

```
import { test as setup } from '@playwright/test';

const authFile = 'playwright/.auth/user.json';

const URL_LOCAL = "http://localhost:8100"

setup('authenticate', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto(URL_LOCAL);

    // Do the login routine here...

    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        window.localStorage.clear();
        window.sessionStorage.clear();

        const indexedDB = window.indexedDB;
        const dbs = await indexedDB.databases();

        for (let dbIndex = 0; dbIndex < dbs.length; dbIndex++) {
            const dbInfo = dbs[dbIndex];
            const db: IDBDatabase = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let req = indexedDB.open(dbInfo.name as string, dbInfo.version);
                req.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
                    resolve(event.target.result);
                }
                req.onupgradeneeded = (event: any) => {
                    resolve(event.target.result);
                }
                req.onerror = (e) => {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });

            let dbRes: { [k: string]: any } = {};

            for (let objectStorageIndex = 0; objectStorageIndex < db.objectStoreNames.length; objectStorageIndex++) {
                const objectStorageName = db.objectStoreNames[objectStorageIndex];
                let objectStorageRes: { [k: string]: any } = {};

                // Open a transaction to access the firebaseLocalStorage object store
                const transaction = db.transaction([objectStorageName], 'readonly');
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStorageName);

                // Get all keys and values from the object store
                const getAllKeysRequest = objectStore.getAllKeys();
                const getAllValuesRequest = objectStore.getAll();

                const keys: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    getAllKeysRequest.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
                        resolve(event.target.result);
                    }
                    getAllKeysRequest.onerror = (e) => {
                        reject(e);
                    }
                });

                const values: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    getAllValuesRequest.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
                        resolve(event.target.result);
                    }
                    getAllValuesRequest.onerror = (e) => {
                        reject(e);
                    }
                });

                for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    objectStorageRes[keys[i]] = JSON.stringify(values[i]);
                }

                dbRes[objectStorageName] = objectStorageRes;
            }
            localStorage.setItem(db.name, JSON.stringify(dbRes));
        }
    });

    await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
});
```

Then we'll need an extra file called `auth.utils.ts` to reconstruct the indexedDB databases, use the following code

```
import { Page } from "@playwright/test";
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const URL_LOCAL = "http://localhost:8100"

export const authenticate = async (page: Page) => {
    await page.goto(URL_LOCAL);

    const auth = JSON.parse(readFileSync('playwright/.auth/user.json', 'utf-8'));

    await page.evaluate(async (auth) => {
        const indexedDB = window.indexedDB;
        const localStorageAuth: any[] = auth.origins[0].localStorage

        for (const storage of localStorageAuth) {
            const dbName = storage.name;
            const dbData = JSON.parse(storage.value as string);
            const tables = Object.keys(dbData);

            const db: IDBDatabase = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let req = indexedDB.open(dbName as string);
                req.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
                    resolve(event.target.result);
                };
                req.onupgradeneeded = (event: any) => {
                    resolve(event.target.result);
                };
                req.onerror = (e) => {
                    reject(e);
                };
                req.onblocked = (event: any) => {
                    reject(event);
                };
            });

            for (const table of tables) {
                const transaction = db.transaction([table], 'readwrite');
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(table);

                for (const key of Object.keys(dbData[table])) {
                    const value = dbData[table][key];

                    // Parse value in case of keyPath
                    let parsedValue = typeof value !== "string" ? JSON.stringify(value) : value;
                    try {
                        parsedValue = JSON.parse(parsedValue);
                    } catch (e) {
                        // value type is not json, nothing to do
                    }

                    if (objectStore.keyPath != null) {
                        objectStore.put(parsedValue);
                    } else {
                        objectStore.put(parsedValue, key);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }, auth);
}
```

And lastly, add this to every test in which you want them to be authenticated:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { authenticate } from './auth.utils';

/// ...

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await authenticate(page);
});

test('example test', async ({ page }) => {
    /// Test content
});

/// More tests
```

Most answers I found on the topic were very specific to the firebase DB, often with the firebase DB name hardcoded, which wasn't very flexible. I have multiple DBs so this code can handle multiple and diverse DBs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent Job! One suggestion is to add a delay (e.g. setTimeout)  to the setup function to allow the firebase data to load completely.

Comment: Great solution! One change from my side: I was getting an error when saving the value back into the IndexedDB. There are a few possible reasons for it, but for the sake of keeping it short, I solved it by filtering out the IndexedDB databases that don't belong to Firebase, in the following way:
`const localStorageAuth: any[] = auth.origins[0].localStorage.filter((val: any) => val.name === 'firebaseLocalStorageDb')`